# How to write the text of textarea on file by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is the first time that I am writing on stackoverflow, so I apologize if I have done something wrong.

I want to write the contents of the textarea to a file.
Can somebody write some code to hang on to my order to save what is written in the textarea?
I really don't know how to and I haven't found any post that talk about it.

Thanks for reply

```
$file = "file";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
echo '<textarea name="ciao" id="ciao" rows="5" cols="40">';
while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
    echo $line;
}
fclose($f);
echo '</textarea>';
```

```html
<textarea type="textarea" id="ciao_hidden" value="ciao_hidden" style="display:none;" ></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    String.prototype.fulltrim=function(){return this.replace(/(?:(?:^|\n)\s+|\s+(?:$|\n))/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');};
    var charfield = document.getElementById("ciao");
    var ch = document.getElementById('ciao_hidden');
    charfield.onkeydown=function(e){
        var str,cv;        
        if (e.keyCode == "13") {    
            console.log(charfield.value);
            cv = charfield.value;
            str = cv.replace(/\n+/g, "<br />");
            ch.value = str;
            console.log(ch.value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on youre reply to my orignal answer, I have come up with the following:*

**test.php**

```
<?php

// Config?
$saveToFile = 'savedText.txt';

// Post Handler
if (count($_POST) && isset($_POST['myText']))
{
    file_put_contents($saveToFile, $_POST['myText']);

    /* 
    // Alternate Save Code - the directory you are working with 
    // must have write permission
    $h = @fopen($saveToFile, 'a');
    if ($h) {
        fwrite($h, $_POST['myText']);
        fclose($h);
    }
    */

    exit('Data Saved.');
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// When Page Loads
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Handle Enter Key In Textarea
    $("#myTextarea").keyup(function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'test.php',
                data: { myText: $(this).val() },
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log('Success : ' + result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>

Enter your text and press enter to save:<br>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

---

Few things to consider:

- This will not be a good idea on a multi-user environment. When 2 or more people are typing, the contents of the file will get overwritten by the last user who pressed enter.
- This is not good for your hard disk (too much I/O, why don't you consider saving it into database?)

Comment: i'm sorry but the text that i write on the textarea must be write on a file, u can visit the test site http://riccardoepietro.altervista.org/prova.php

Comment: So you want to let users type stuff in a textarea and then when they click save, write that to a file on your server?

Comment: yes user write on textarea and every time you press enter the contents of the textarea should be written to the file

Comment: only one person will be able to write in don't worry

Comment: mmmmmmm doesn't work.
I tried to put your code directly changing the file name but nothing.

Comment: Hi. I posted the answer after I tested it and it works. I am on windows WAMP. If you are on linux machine; Make sure the target file myou are writing to `savedText.txt` exists on your server next to your script and also has write permission by PHP.

Comment: I think that is the right solution but if you open the elements ispector on http://riccardoepietro.altervista.org/prova.php and try it you can see the error 404

Comment: @riccardo-osmosit you need to change `url: 'test.php',` to reflect your filename: `url: 'prova.php',`

Comment: oooooo man xD
of course .-.
really really thanks and thanks again and again :D

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can make content downloadable with javascript using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

With jquery, something like this would make a `<a>` element right after the textarea to prompt the user to download the textareas content as a text file

```
$('textarea + a').each(function(i){
    var txt = new Blob([$(this).prev().val()], {type:'text/plain'});
    $(this)
        .prop('download', $(this).html())
        .prop('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(txt) );
});
```

Comment: This is awesome if latest FireFox was the only browser in the world :)

Comment: @latheesan-kanes Its been in chrome since version 20, FF since 13, IE10, opera 12, safari 6 according to the page i linked. Way more widely available then "the latest firefox". Besides, prior to this, there was no way to automatically download content as a file, you'd have to post it to the server and have it generate the file for you.

Comment: i'm sorry can u explain this code because i need a code that every time you press enter the contents of the textarea should be written to the file

Comment: @riccardo-osmosit This code makes whatever is in the textarea on load to be available for download. You could take this and instead of running immediately, attach it to a click handler to get the current content, and push that blob to the user. 
Dont get me wrong, this code does not write to a file on your client, nor on your server. It makes it possible to _download_ content that becomes a file when you do.

Comment: I understand that this could be really useful and I thank you for the answers, but I'm making an easy control of the editing texts; then the text will be written in the textarea I need that it remains only on the server. The downlod of this file by the user should not be enabled. What will be written in the textarea, for each submission must be saved in the file.

Comment: @riccardo-osmosit Well, in that case what you seek is that which Latheesan Kanes provided.
Javascript only run in the client, so to get something to happen on the server you need to tell the server to do it.